# Ruby on Rails PaperClip Gem validate_attachement error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, paperclip, attachment

I have googled/stack overflowed for hours and not found a solution to this problem.  I'm wondering if my installation of PaperClip was somehow unsuccessful.  I'm trying to validate an image attachment in my models folder:

```
validates :image, presence: true,
content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']},
size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }
```

I have also tried code more similiar to the read me file on github:

```
validates_attachment :image, :presence => true,
:content_type => { :content_type => 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif' },
:size => { less_than: => 5.megabytes }
```

And I've tried to use individual validations

```
validates_attachment_presence :image
validates_attachment_content_type :image,:content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
validates_attachment_size :image,:less_than => 5.megabytes
```

I get an error in all cases.  Either:

```
Routing Error
undefined method `before_image_post_process' for #<Class:0x00000101461750>
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Or:

```
NoMethodError in PinsController#index
undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 34):

Do you have `has_attached_file :image` in your file?
If so, make sure it is before `validates_attachment`.

Comment: You are right @savmac, order is important. I has same issue, but I remember I read somewhere that, associations should always before validation.

Comment: Paperclip could throw better error in case it fails to find attachment passed to `validates_attachment`!

Answer (score 4):

I keep getting this error each time just because I always forget to rename the image variable the same way (after copying from the snippet):

```
has_attached_file :avatar...

validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type...
```

→ Should be also `:avatar` instead of `:photo`

It's a perfect example of how problems may arize when the code is not DRY.

Answer (score 1):

savmac's fix worked for me just now. i was having the same problem upon heroku open. the lines in the model had been out of order previously and my app had worked seamlessly for months--dunno what changed. thanks!